# iOS Swift - Presenting View Controller sliding down while presenting new View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I present a View Controller in the following fashion:

```
let vc: ChangeDateViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("changedate") as! ChangeDateViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) //ensures that the top navigation bar remains in the new View Controller
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For some reason, the base presenting View Controller slides down while the new View Controller is sliding up. Although the presenting works, it does look glitchy because the sliding down reveals the black background behind the views. Is this a common occurrence, and is there anything I can do to prevent it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let conn = storyboard1.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("changedate") as! LMAddaccountMainVC
self.presentViewController(conn, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This might be helpful to solve you issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference :/ This also removes the UINavigationController aspect of my code, so I end up not having a navigation bar on the new View Controller.